# how to create a dot file for default mac settings

Tags: terminal, bash

## Background

I have a habit of creating new user profiles on my mac that serves different needs (ie recruiting, software development etc). I'm always thinking of ways to make creating a new user less expensive, one is saving all sorts of setting files and saving them in dropbox (ie alfred settings, slate settings, bash_profile, vimrc etc etc).

I also have many settings that I have to issue mac commands for (like [this](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2014/06/15/how-to-change-where-screenshots-are-saved-on-mac/) one):

```
defaults write com.apple.screencapture location ~/Documents/Screenshots   
killall SystemUIServer
```

How can I save these in a "dot file", and simply have the system read them on load (ie like ~/.bash_profile)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- create a bash script for all the config commands, e.g.

  ```
  #!/bin/bash

  defaults write com.apple.screencapture location ~/Documents/Screenshots   
  killall SystemUIServer
  ```
- store it in `/usr/local/bin` under whatever name you like
- run it once for each new account

Comment: this code `defaults write com.apple.screencapture location ~/Documents/Screenshots` isn't bashscript.. i'm not even sure what language it is.. so that won't work

Comment: For any future users looking, `defaults` is an included Apple binary, and will work perfectly fine from a bash script.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing is probably to create an app bundle that executes any number of arbitrary things, then add it to your login items under System Preferences -> Users and Groups -> Login Items.

[image]

I'd recommend using AppleScript to do be the middleman. Create a new Applescript to run your task, then go to File -> Export... and choose Application.

[image]

Alternatively you can just add it to your `~/.bash_profile` if you'd like. There's a possibility this isn't configure to run on startup because macOS; if that's the case, just add it to your `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: so can apple script run `defaults write com.apple.screencapture location ~/Documents/Screenshots` ???

Comment: Sure. `do shell script "defaults write com.apple.screencapture location ~/Documents/Screenshots"`